# CSS/HTML Boxes side by side

Tags: html, css

Having some problems getting my 4 grey boxes all displayed on the same line. Thought by giving them each a 25% width they would automatically each display a 1/4 screen size no matter ones resolution or screen size. Get the first 3, but the fourth one drops down on the next line. Any ideas on how to force them all on the same line?

HTML

```
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>
<div class="b4"></div>
```

CSS

```
.b1, .b2, .b3, .b4 {
   display:inline-block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 5px;
   float:left;
   width:25%;
   height:400px;
   background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).  The reason why they're not floating side by side on the same line is because you're adding a margin.  This margin is not considered in the height or width of your content area.  If you used something other than margin, you could use the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property, but that's not the best approach.  Ideally, you'd compensate for your margin, so something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4Kvj/1) should get you started.

Obligatory addition: the widths add up to **92%** leaving **8%** to work with, so if you add a margin-left of 1% and margin-right of 1%, that gets multiplied by 4 items using the margin property (gives you 8% for the required width), you've got all 100% width accounted for.

**HTML**

```
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.b {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to `float:left` there is no reason to have `display:inline-block;`

Comment: Yup, agreed... I was just addressing the issue at hand.

Comment: that was more for the OP than for you. I figured you just changed what needed to be changed for it work.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot 
HTML

```
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>
<div class="b4"></div>
```

CSS

```
.b1, .b2, .b3, .b4{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
    width: calc(25% - 10px);
    height:400px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

As you can see with the width, we use **calc()** and use the original 25% width minus the 10px of margin you have left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Your margin is what is causing the issue.  Look at it this way, each of the 4 divs requires 25% of the page width PLUS a 5 pixel left margin and a 5 pixel right margin.  So your margins either need to be percentage based or you need to decrease the percentage width of each div to allow for the margin.

Comment: They should also be `display: block` and not `inline-block` as the latter will obey single whitespaces between them.